# Remove div inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my initial HTML:

```
<div id="image_holder_119">
  <div id="holder_rotate_119">
   <div class="loading_bag">
     <div class="loading">
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to remove the div having class `"loading"`. Something like this:

```
<div id="image_holder_119">
  <div id="holder_rotate_119">
   <div class="loading_bag">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to read some basic tutos... Really, you should! BTW, what about using google?

Comment: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) is all you need to learn the basics

Answer (score 4):

use `.remove()`:

```
 $('.loading_bag .loading').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NL3U9/)**

Comment: but "image_holder_119" and "holder_rotate_119" ids are dynamic..this may change

Comment: So what. I have not used ID selectors because of same.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.parent_class .child_class').remove();
```

In your case, that would be:

```
$('.loading_bag .loading').remove();
```